# The type 'Type' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: .net

Below errror occures when you build a .NET project:

> The type 'Type' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0'

Answer (score 0):

Open Visual Studio Installer from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\setup.exe` and install the `.NET SDK`.

[image]